# Change data capture and linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am new to linq and cdc. I am trying to view the cdc log file updates using c# and linq. Basically what i need help with, is how to implement this show update query using c# and linq.

```
USE mytest;
GO
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn =
   sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_User_Info')
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT ID_number, Name, Age FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_User_Info
  (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');
GO
```

I can easily see all the changes made to mytest table in sql server using this query, but how can i implement it using linq to sql. I am using sql server 2008 and visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to map a table valued function to an entity in Linq?

How to: Use Table-Valued User-Defined Functions in LINQ:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUserHistory()
    RETURNS table AS
RETURN (

    SELECT ID_number, Name, Age FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_User_Info
    ((SELECT sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_User_Info')), (SELECT sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()),N'all')
)
```